# ompatibility Issue with 'url_launcher_ios' Plugin in iOS Deployment Target

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-dependencies

Upon attempting to run the application on an iOS device, I encountered the following error:

```
Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'open(_:options:completionHandler:)' is only available in iOS 10.0 or newer
/Users/apple/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/url_launcher_ios-6.2.1/ios/Classes/Launcher.swift:29:29
```

My project's deployment target is set to platform: iOS '11.0'. Surprisingly, the application runs smoothly when I remove the 'url_launcher_ios' plugin. After conducting thorough research, I found that the error seems to be associated with the 'url_launcher_ios' plugin itself, even though I have ensured that both my application and the plugin are using the latest available versions.

This compatibility issue is causing hindrances in utilizing the 'url_launcher_ios' plugin effectively within the specified deployment target. I've attempted to resolve this by updating to the latest plugin version and exploring other potential solutions within the limitations of the iOS deployment target, but unfortunately, the issue persists.

Could you kindly provide guidance or assistance in resolving this matter? It would be immensely appreciated if there are any workarounds, updates, or fixes available that could facilitate seamless integration of the 'url_launcher_ios' plugin within the context of an iOS deployment target of '11.0' or higher.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you set the deployment target only in your `Podfile`. You also need to do this in Xcode, in target's General tab:

[image]

Comment: My minimum Deployments in target's General tab is 11.0 and still, I'm getting an error in Xcode is "Launcher.swift:30:30 'open(_:options:completionHandler:)' is only available in iOS 10.0 or newer", "URLLauncherPlugin.swift:24:43 Default argument value of type 'UIApplication' does not conform to 'Launcher'", "/URLLauncherPlugin.swift:45:60 'universalLinksOnly' is only available in iOS 10.0 or newer"